# Android. Unable to get data when using token

Tags: android, get, retrofit

In my application, I am trying to access the list of repositories of an authorized user using the documentation: https://docs.github.com/ru/rest/users/users?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-authenticated-user.

But when I get a response, I get the following error:

```json
{
  "message": "Requires authentication",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/users/users#get-the-authenticated-user"
}
```

Code from my app:

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("users/{username}")
    suspend fun getUserInfo(@Header("Authorization") accessToken: String, @Path("username") username: String): Response<ResponseBody>

    @Headers(
        "Accept: application/vnd.github+json",
        "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28")
    @GET("user")
    suspend fun getGithubRepositories(@Header("Authorization") accessToken: String): Response<ResponseBody>
}
```

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesBaseUrl(): String = "https://api.github.com/"

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(BASE_URL: String): Retrofit {

        val contentType = "application/json".toMediaType()
        return  Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType))
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(retrofit: Retrofit): ApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideUserInfoRepository( mainService: ApiService): UserInfoRepository =UserInfoRepository(mainService)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGithubRepositoriesRepository( mainService: ApiService): GithubRepositoriesRepository =GithubRepositoriesRepository(mainService)

}
```

I tried sending a request on the website https://reqbin.com /, and the result is correct. I've looked at a few examples of how I created the code in the application, but nothing works for me. And I can't figure out where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the word *Bearer* before your access token. That way the header will read like *Authorization: Bearer YOUR-TOKEN*

```kotlin
val token = "YOUR-TOKEN"
val response = api.getGithubRepositories(accessToken = "Bearer $token")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding the Bearer keyword, but it didn't help. I noticed that the code works if I don't use Dagger-hilt. But when using Dagger-hilt, I don't get the data for the authorized user

Comment: That's strange. Can you provide your GithubRepositoriesRepository implementation?

Comment: I was able to get an answer using OkhttpBuilder and Interceptor using the example from the article: https://www.valueof.io/blog/basic-auth-okhttp-retrofit-dagger         But I have another problem. I get the data using GsonConverterFactory.create(). But when I use kotlin serialization addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory(contentType)) according to the example from the article https://vtsen.hashnode.dev/simple-rest-api-android-app-in-kotlin-various-http-client-library-implementations, I don't get any data

Comment: `class GithubRepositoriesRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: ApiService
) {

    suspend fun getGithubRepositories(token: String) = apiService.getAllUserRepos(token)
}`